# why `S x({})` invoke default constructor in GCC 7/C++1z mode only?

Tags: c++, gcc, language-lawyer, c++17

In the following snippet, GCC 7 with C++1z mode invokes the default constructor, but GCC/C++14 and Clang/C++14,C++1z invoke the initializer-list constructor.

Is this behavior affected by any C++1z Specifiation change (possibly [Guaranteed copy elision](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0135r1.html)?), or GCC bug?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <initializer_list>

struct S {
  S() { std::printf("DEF "); }      // (1)
  S(std::initializer_list<int> il)  // (2)
    { std::printf("L=%zu ", il.size()); }
};

int main() {
  S x({});
}
```

Output:

- [gcc 7.1.0/-std=c++14](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iACdbGKRhtYLgvD8): `L=0`
- [gcc 7.1.0/-std=c++1z](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ajf8qDTPiw9XisVb): `DEF`
- [Clang HEAD 5.0.0/-std=c++14 and c++1z](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Dvk8z2ZAhzfzKeQU): `L=0`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think this is a gcc bug (submitted as [80804](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80804)). The order of rules for [dcl.init] in C++17 is:

> If the destination type is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type:
>
> - If the initializer expression is a prvalue and the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as the class of the destination, the initializer expression is used to initialize the destination object.

That first bullet does not apply. The initializer expression here is `{}`, which isn't even an expression so it doesn't even have a cv-unqualified type to compare against `S`. This bullet *would* apply if we had written `S x(S{})` instead.

> - Otherwise, if the initialization is direct-initialization, or if it is copy-initialization where the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as, or a derived class of, the class of the destination, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated ([over.match.ctor]), and the best one is chosen through overload resolution. The constructor so selected is called to initialize the object, with the initializer expression or expression-list as its argument(s). If no constructor applies, or the overload resolution is ambiguous, the initialization is ill-formed.

This is direct-initialization, so constructors are considered as per [over.match.ctor], which just tells is to overload on the constructors. Since there is a `std::initializer_list` constructor, that one gets priority per [over.ics.rank], so that one is selected.

---

The only difference between C++14 and C++17 here is the introduction of that first bullet - which doesn't apply anyway, so the behavior should be the same.

Comment: Stack Overflow, where compiler bugs are found from unusual questions.

Comment: @InternetAussie the problem is that not everyone files a bug report

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Indeed, but at least some people like Barry are kind enough to proactively submit these issues to those who can fix them! Thanks for that.